# How to Uncheck Legend Items in Teechart through c# Code?

Tags: c#, teechart

Is there any way in Teechart,which allow us to change state of Legend Item Check box programatically using c#??? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjqTI.png)

Comment: I would recommend to visit the [Teechart support forum](http://www.teechart.net/support/index.php) to ask product-related questions.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, the Steema/TeeChart forum is a good place to go; the question may already be there.

The Legend item checkbox controls Series visible (Active). If you programatically toggle Series.Active it will repaint the Legend CheckBox accordingly.

eg. (here for 1st Series in Chart)

```
tChart1[0].Active = !tChart1[0].Active;
```